# c#: Where to put my API and what should go into MyCOmpanyName.MyProduct.Core (core) namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, naming-conventions

can anyone help me with bit of refactoring advice.

I have my App which i have in the namespace - these namespaces i am happy with.

```
  MyCompany.MyProduct.Web (for the web app)

  MyCompany.MyProduct.Windows (for the windows app)
```

these apps need to call my API .. The API is specifically for this application but lives separately. Currently I have it in the following form.

```
  MyCompany.MyProduct.Api
```

But i really don't like it... i was thinking maybe better to put it in

```
  MyCompany.MyProduct.Core
```

Is this a good way?

Under Core i will have Enums, Exception Classes etc

So these would be actually

```
  MyCompany.MyProduct.Core.Enums.DaysOfWeek (DaysOfWeek is an example)

  MyCompany.MyProduct.Core.Exceptions.ConnectionException (just an example)
```

Is Core a good idea and what should go in there.????

If I have a command called CreateSchedule which is under the class Schedule which is part of my api then what would be a good idea for the complete namespace including method etc

```
             MyCompany.MyProduct.Core.Schedule.CreateSchedule   ???
```

I presume i put under the ROOT (i.e. CORE) all enums / exceptions that are globally specific to my api. Is it good practice that my app can use Enums /Exceptions from my API - this is how i currentlt have it. if i have an enum that is specific only to a class do i keep it there in ROOT (core) or better to put it

```
             MyCompany.MyProduct.Core.Schedule.Enums
```

I hope someone can help me on this

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you planning on separating enums, exceptions, etc. into their own namespaces? Namespaces should be *logical* divisions of code, not arbitrary ones based on implementation details. The exceptions and enums related to a particular function all belong in the same namespace.

Comment: thanks.. thats what i was looking for! a confirmation.... going pull them out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I think if an enum applies to only a specific class, then it makes sense to make the enum be within that class (i.e. not at the root level). For exampe, it makes sense for DaysOfWeek to be within the Schedule class.
- "Core" is certainly better than "Api", which sort of looks weird since it's an acronym.
- I am not sure about having a namespace for Exceptions (i.e. MyCompany.MyProduct.Core.Exceptions.xxx). I would rather put the exception classes as siblings of the class from which they are generated.

Comment: thanks for the input!  i think your right...  so i presume the same would go for Enums i.e. No namespace for enums just place them as seperate file in the same namespace as CORE?

Comment: Is the word CORE good for insert "ALL" of my api in there?  I know others are using Core but i can't seem to find any reference...  The word CORE means the core of the application i presume - so a good place for the API? Or not?

Comment: Either Core or just remove it entirely (i.e. MyCompany.MyProduct). That way it's implicit that anything at the root is "core". Just like everything in the System namespace is core in .NET.

Comment: Yeah definitely no separate namespace for enums. Typically a namespace is used to group classes by functionality (i.e. MyCompany.MyProductA, MyCompany.MyProductB etc). At least, that's how I use them.